# Bash - For loop not working with variables in the declaration

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

```
for i in {0..3}
do
   echo $i
done
```

returns

```
0
1
2
3
```

but

```
firstNumber=$1
lastNumber=$2

for i in {$firstNumber..$lastNumber}
do
   echo $i
done
```

returns, for example,

```
{0..3}
```

What can I do to use variables in a For loop declaration?

Comment: Note that in bash, `{$min..$max}` does not work. They have to be static numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ((i=$firstNumber; i <= $lastNumber; i++)); do echo $i; done
```